# How to choose an eigenvector of ([1,-1,0],[1,2,1],[-2,1,-1])

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I've found the eigenvalues of this matrix:

$$
\begin{bmatrix} 
1&-1&0 \\
1&2&1\\
-2&1&-1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\quad
$$

They are 1, -1 and 2. For $\lambda$ = 1. I get the equations:

$x-y = x$   (eqtn: 1)

$x+2y +z = y$ (eqtn: 2)

$-2x+y-z=z$    (eqtn: 3)

How do I figure out the eigenvector equation from those? I don't know what to do with (1) as the x's cancel out. Does this mean all values of x hold true, or only x = 0?

Thanks,

Comment: If $\vec v$ is an eigenvector, so is any non-zero scalar multiple of $\vec v$

Comment: There’s nothing special about eigenvectors in this regard. How would you go about finding the solution to any other undetermined system of linear equations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track, there is nothing to worry about. From $(1)$ we get $y=0$, plugging into $(2)$ and $(3)$ gives $x+z=0$. Hence $\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix}$ is an eigenvector for the eigenvalue $\lambda=1$, but also any scalar multiple of this vector.

Comment: Thanks! So is it safe to assume that (1)  is true for all x, so we pick the smallest non-zero value, i.e. 1? Also since x = -z. is the vector(-1.0,1) just as valid?

Comment: Well, we just have to pick $x$ and $z$ such that $x+z=0$. You can pick whatever non-zero number $a$ you like, let that be your $x$, as long as you let $z=-a$.